# NeTBeans Web Application Project gives a error message HTTP Status 404

Tags: netbeans, webproject

When I run the project directly right clicking the project name I get a error     "HTTP status 404" but when i individually run a file (eg. home.html) it runs.The project is a servlet project, where my home.html is connected to a servlet file.There are no errors for sure. What's the real issue?

Answer (score 0):

404 errors are generated by the web container when a resource is not found. Clearly there must be an issue with your paths or something, but based on the limited information you provide it is hard to spot the mistake...